# google+ Api - get activity

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I have problem when I get activity from Google+ API I expected to find location field which is not exist

I found that location should be display as its shown in activity response [resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource). However when i used [resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource)
 to get all public activity i didn't find location field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google APIs can only return the information that they currently have

```
 "location": {
    "kind": "plus#place",
    "id": string,
    "displayName": string,
    "position": {
      "latitude": double,
      "longitude": double
    },
    "address": {
      "formatted": string
    }
```

Is filled out by Google Places if the activity wasn't inserted with the places information then the information will not be available.   To my knowledge this information is only filled out when you add location to a post on Google+ other wise it will be left blank.

Comment: so location will only return when the user add it with his post ? am i right?

Comment: Yes as far as i know that can only be done via an android app on the Google+ website.    there is a little Share your location button on the bottom of the post message.